# JS/JQUERY: Is it ok to manipulate non-existing elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in a situation where I need to set HTML contents for a bunch of divs spans form inputs etc on a page through a custom displayData() function.

I feed it an array of key->value pairs where the key is the element name, class, or ID.

Right now, my function is testing for specific ID, Class name, and form names, and if they exist, i set the HTML or VALUE accordingly. My script is more complex than this but what I am trying to get at is that my function has become so complex with lots of conditions, etc.

After a lot of code, i realized, why not i just target all elements that matches my key.

That way if I have, say

```
 myData['color_group_x'] = "blue";
```

Why don't i just target all all possible elements with that "color_group_x" selector, eg:

```
  $("#color_group_x").html("blue");
  $(".color_group_x").html("blue");
  $("[name='color_group_x']").html("blue");  //note: i deal w/ selects/radios/checks separately.
```

This way, i dont have to worry about testing for existing elements and element types anymore.

Is this fine? Or very detrimental to performance?

Honestly, I went ahead and did this already and boy is it much easier to implement and the results are more reliable. But I'm just concerned if this is something that is very wrong?

Comment: jQuery is going to happily handle the non-existent cases for you as a no-op. And there wouldn't be a performance penalty or anything. `$("missingID")` results in an empty jQuery container and doing any modifications on an empty container is a safe no-op.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this, if the result of `$(selector)` is an empty list, jQuery simply does nothing when you try to manipulate it.

Comment: fraking awesome . lovit! thanks for the confirmation @VLAZ and @ Chris G  ..this would make my life so much easier for this current project. thanks again!